# How to download Excel file with HttpClient instead of WebClient in .NET?

Tags: c#, webclient, dotnet-httpclient

I have the following code

```
private void SaveFile(string linkToFile, string filename)
{
    using WebClient client = new();
    client.DownloadFile(linkToFile, ResourcePath + filename);
}
```

So my question is, how can I download Excel file with HttpClient instead of WebClient?

Comment: https://www.aspnetmonsters.com/2016/08/2016-08-27-httpclientwrong/

Comment: https://josef.codes/you-are-probably-still-using-httpclient-wrong-and-it-is-destabilizing-your-software/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The best source of documentation on `HttpClient` is, of course, the Microsoft site itself:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.httpclient
Here's an (oversimplified) version of the code I use for downloading spreadsheets:

```
private async Task SaveFile(string fileUrl, string pathToSave)
{
    // See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.httpclient
    // for why, in the real world, you want to use a shared instance of HttpClient
    // rather than creating a new one for each request
    var httpClient = new HttpClient();
    
    var httpResult = await httpClient.GetAsync(fileUrl);
    using var resultStream = await httpResult.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync();
    using var fileStream = File.Create(pathToSave);
    resultStream.CopyTo(fileStream);
}
```

Comment: I'd rather go for `async Task` instead of `async void` or is there a specific reason you've used void?

Comment: @Marco as I said, "oversimplified" :-)